# Делаю api запрос через прокси, но все равно получаю ошибку

Tags: api, proxy, steam, steam-web-api

Выполняю запросы к steam api, через какое-то количество выполнений кода для меня ограничевается доступ (даже когда стараюсь делать промежутки по 2-5 минут). Решил попробовать сделать это через прокси, но какой-бы ip не выбрал ловлю одну и туже ошибку.
Код:

```
address = '103.155.217.156'
port = '41471'

proxies = {
    'http': f'http://{address}:{port}',
    'https': f'https://{address}:{port}',
}

for i in assets:
    assetid = int(str(i.get('assetid')))
    classid = i.get('classid')
    
    if classid in hash_price.keys():
        price = hash_price[classid]
    else:
        name = ""
        for j in descriptions:
            if j.get('classid') == classid:
                name = j.get('market_hash_name')
                break
        
        url1 = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&country=ru&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + name + "&format=json"

        resp = requests.get(url=url1, proxies=proxies)
        data2 = resp.json()
```

Полученная ошибка: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='steamcommunity.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /market/priceoverview/?currency=5&country=ru&appid=730&market_hash_name=Sticker%20%7C%20Evil%20Geniuses%20%7C%202020%20RMR&format=json (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy. Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)'))))
Я думал, что должна помочь подмена ip через прокси, но не помогает. Толкните пожалуйста в сторону решения, заранее очень признателен!